# can a vbscript hide the console that launched it?

Tags: windows, vbscript

I am launching from the command line a vbscript like this:

> cscript.exe myscript.vbs

can I add something inside myscript.vbs to hide the console that launched it?

Comment: What's the contents of myscript.vbs and what's your purpose do it in this way ?

Comment: it is just openning a vbscript inputbox. In fact, from C code, I call _popen with "cscript.exe myscript.vbs" and I'd like to hide the console (created by _popen) via the vbscript.

Comment: It could close it, or minimize (but this might also not be the greatest idea) it but not hide it imo. Why would you launch it from console if you do not want a console window though?

Comment: I think minimize would do the job. how can I do this? I don't really want a console, but _popen opens it anyway.

Comment: what about starting the script with `wscipt.exe` instead of `cscript.exe`? wscript.exe has no any user interface or console

Comment: wscript or cscript ? in any case _popen always opens a console windows

Answer (score 0):

In general you can minimize a Program from Vbscript by using sendkeys and sending the sequence <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> + whatever key is the shortcut for minimize in your local language. (You can check this in the GUI by pressing <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> and looking for the underlined character in the minimize option)

In german and english this would be

```
wso.SendKeys "% n"
```

However this method is buggy with cmd and will not work since Windows XP. So the best workaround I found is a horrible hack where you use a call to powershell.exe.

The question for you is whether your program immediately steals the focus of the hosting cmd.exe or not. If not you can just insert

```
Set wso = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
wso.SendKeys "powershell -windowstyle minimized -command """"{ENTER}"
```

If you somehow lose the focus on the cmd, you have to regain it. You could do that by using:

```
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")

' WQL uses \ as escpae char so we need to escape it with an additional \
wmiScriptName = Replace(wscript.ScriptFullName, "\", "\\")


Set colProcesses = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Process Where CommandLine like '%" & wmiScriptName & "%'")

For Each objProcess in colProcesses
    wso.AppActivate objProcess.ProcessId
    wso.SendKeys "powershell -windowstyle minimized -command """"{ENTER}"
Next
```

This will minimize all cmds that have the script running so it should not be started multiple times.. The WQL query is also not perfect, so if you edit the script in notepad for example it will detect this as well and send keys there... If this is a use case you think will happen you have to be more exact with your WQL query (include processname cscript.exe or something)

It is quite a hack but I could not think of any other way of doing this in vbscript only (sadly one external call is necessary but no code executed and powershell.exe should be present everywhere). If you could do the whole script in powershell for example there would probably be better methods.

Comment: I am already using powershell to hide the console, and it works fine. BUT there is not guaranty that powershell is allowed to run scripts on the target machine. This is why I'd like a vbscript solution.

Comment: About the only advantage of this powershell call is that it doesn't execute anything. It will run even if you set executionpolicy to signedonly. In generally I mostly answered for the heck of it to show what is imo possible in vbs and what not. The real question is could you not far more easily hide the console window from the c program? Or could you not execute it in a way no console window is produced? Also is the popen console a real cmd? if not the sendkeys % n might work after all (the detection of the windows process id might be different though)

Answer (score 0):

Is this a batch file?

If so, if that's the only line, you can put

```
EXIT
```

after your code and it will close the console once the vbscript opens.

As for hiding the console, you can run the batch from a vbs as shown here: http://www.howtogeek.com/131597/can-i-run-a-windows-batch-file-without-a-visible-command-prompt/